# Architecture of windows services from .Net point of view

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, service

Several windows services can share one process. In C# they will start as:

```
ServiceBase.Run(new MyService1(), new MyService2());
```

The call of run method blocks the thread where `main()` executes. At the same time events of services are handled. So where are they executed?

Do they use Asynchronous Procedure Call in the "main" process that is not just blocked but is in alertable waiting? If it's so, the sharing a process for multiple services has drawback in performance.  Do handlers run in separate threads? Are they executed outside of the process containing the `Run()` call?

Comment: You asked 7 questions.  You'll have to pare it down to *one*.

Comment: @HansPassant Questions 2-5 are just clarification of the first. I removed 6, 7.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, multiple services can share a single process by using the [SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx) service type. .NET have to use this service type to register multiple services in a single process on Windows.

Every registered service has a name and a native entry point address represented by the [SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686001(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. .NET shall construct a `SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY` for each service passed to the `ServiceBase.Run` method, and call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` function with these information.

To receive notifications about service status, the entry point (`ServiceMain` as implemented by `ServiceBase` class) must call [RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058(v=vs.85).aspx) to receive notifications. These notifications are sent using APCs. As a side note, [NotifyServiceStatusChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684276(v=vs.85).aspx) API also uses APCs.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably are after is the windows service architecture and how service applications are integrated in them.

There is already a very good article on that topic in the MSDN, [which can be found here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998749%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx)

It not only explains how Windows interacts with services, how the services database works (at least partly).

The article also explains how operating system services work and gives some hint on hosting services in the IIS (Internet information services).